# JS Property Synonyms using getter and setter

Tags: javascript, class, coding-style, getter-setter, synonym

Lately I asked myself, if I could create property synonyms using getters and setters like in this example for a class:

```
class Vector{
    constructor(m=0,d=0){
        this.m = m;
        this.d = d;
    }
    get magnitude(){
        return this.m;
    }
    get direction(){
        return this.d;
    }
    set magnitude(magnitude){
        this.m = magnitude;
    }
    set direction(direction){
        this.d = direction;
    }
}
```

First of all I want to know if this is "bad practice" or if it is an accepted way of enabling the class user to use it like he wants to.

Also I'd be intrested in possible alternatives for property synonyms.

Thanks for your help :^)

Comment: Doing it as regular practice seems like it would be confusing, but it would be a useful way to implement a migration from poor property names to better names.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the tip :)